# how to return value to parameter in between getintent and putintents

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I have this product getters and setters i want the boolean below (boolean=added) to be changed to true when it is clicked and back to false when its clicked again. More information below: code below is the getters and setters

```
 package kfc.project;

    public class Product {


        String name;
        int servingSize;
        int calories;
        int fat;
        int saturatedFat;
        int transFat;
        int cholesterol;
        int sodium;
        int carbs;
        int fiber;
        int sugar;
        int protein;
        int vitamina;
        int vitaminc;
        int calcium;
        int iron;
        boolean added;

        public Product (String name, int servingSize, int calories, int fat, int saturatedFat, int transFat, int cholesterol, int sodium, int carbs, int fiber, int sugar, int protein, int vitamina, int vitaminc, int calcium, int iron){
            this.name=name;
            this.calories=calories;
            this.servingSize=servingSize;
            this.fat=fat;
            this.saturatedFat=saturatedFat;
            this.transFat=transFat;
            this.cholesterol=cholesterol;
            this.fiber=fiber;
            this.sugar=sugar;
            this.sodium=sodium;
            this.carbs=carbs;
            this.protein=protein;
            this.vitamina=vitamina;
            this.vitaminc=vitaminc;
            this.calcium=calcium;
            this.iron=iron;
            added = false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){

                return name;

        }

        public Product (String name, int servingSize){
            this.name=name;
            this.servingSize=servingSize;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getServingSize() {
            return servingSize;
        }

        public int getCalories() {
            return calories;
        }

        public int getFat() {
            return fat;
        }

        public int getSaturatedFat() {
            return saturatedFat;
        }

        public int getTransFat() {
            return transFat;
        }

        public int getCholesterol() {
            return cholesterol;
        }

        public int getSodium() {
            return sodium;
        }

        public int getCarbs() {
            return carbs;
        }

        public int getProtein() {
            return protein;
        }

        public int getFiber(){
            return fiber;
        }

        public int getSugar(){
            return sugar;
        }
        public int getVitaminA(){
            return vitamina;
        }
        public int getVitaminC(){
            return vitaminc;
        }
        public int getCalcium(){
            return calcium;
        }
        public int getIron(){
            return iron;
        }
        public void setAdded(boolean x){
            added = x;
        }
        public boolean getAdded(){
            return added;
        }

    }
```

This is the arraylist where the information is stored and is transfered to a list view

```
package kfc.project;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductList {
    ArrayList<Product> list;


    public ProductList (){
        list = new ArrayList<Product>();

        //CREATE PRODUCT HERE
        Product chicken;
        list.add(new Product("Chicken", 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 80,70,60,50,40,30));    

        Product rice;
        list.add(new Product("Rice",11));
    }

    public String[] getNames (){
        int c = 0;
        int size = list.size() - 1;
        String[] names = new String[size];

        while (size >= c) {
            //names.add(list.get(c).getName());
            names[c] = list.get(c).getName();
            c++;
        }

        c = 0;

        return names;
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getList (){
        return list;
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the listview where there is an intent that transfers it to another java file where the xml file is located

```
package kfc.project;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProductListView extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ProductList pl = new ProductList();

        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, PRODUCTS));
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this, R.layout.list_item, pl.getList() ));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "View Product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Product product = pl.getList().get(position);
            // intent stuff for product detail
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProductListView.this, productdetail.class);
            //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            //intent.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra("list", pl.getList());
            intent.putExtra("name",product.getName());
            intent.putExtra("serving size", product.getServingSize());
            intent.putExtra("calories", product.getCalories());
            intent.putExtra("fat", product.getFat());
            intent.putExtra("saturated fat", product.getSaturatedFat());
            intent.putExtra("trans fat", product.getTransFat());
            intent.putExtra("cholesterol", product.getCholesterol());
            intent.putExtra("sodium", product.getSodium());
            intent.putExtra("carbs", product.getCarbs());
            intent.putExtra("fiber", product.getFiber());
            intent.putExtra("sugar", product.getSugar());
            intent.putExtra("protein", product.getProtein());
            intent.putExtra("vitamina", product.getVitaminA());
            intent.putExtra("vitaminc", product.getVitaminC());
            intent.putExtra("calcium", product.getCalcium());
            intent.putExtra("iron", product.getIron());
            intent.putExtra("added", product.getAdded());

            ProductListView.this.startActivity(intent);

            //startActivity(new Intent("kfc.project.productdetail"));
          }

        });

    }

}
```

Now this is the xml java file wherein i want to define boolean whenever the button is clicked. How can i do this

```
package kfc.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class productdetail extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.productdetail);
        //stuff to get intent
        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();


        String productName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");
        int productServingSize = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("serving size",0);
        int productCalories = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("calories",0);
        int productFat = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("fat",0);
        int productSaturatedFat = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("saturated fat",0);
        int productTransFat = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("trans fat",0);
        int productCholesterol = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("cholesterol",0);
        int productSodium = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("sodium",0);
        int productCarbs = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("carbs",0);
        int productFiber = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("fiber",0);
        int productSugar = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("sugar",0);
        int productProtein = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("protein",0);
        int productVitaminA = receivedIntent.getIntExtra ("vitamina",0);
        int productVitaminC = receivedIntent.getIntExtra ("vitaminc",0);
        int productCalcium = receivedIntent.getIntExtra ("calcium",0);
        int productIron = receivedIntent.getIntExtra ("iron",0);
        boolean added = receivedIntent.getBooleanExtra("added", false);

        //BUTTONS
        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button removeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        String name = extras.getString("name");

        if (name != null) {
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productname);
            text1.setText(productName);

        }

        //SHOW/HIDE 'ADD' & 'REMOVE' BUTTONS
        if (added==false) {
            //HIDE 'REMOVE' BUTTON
            removeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //SHOW 'ADD' BUTTON
            addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
        }else{
            //SHOW 'REMOVE' BUTTON
            removeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
            //HIDE 'ADD' BUTTON         
            addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        }

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //added=true;
            }       
        });

        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //added=false;
            }       
        });


            TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.servingsize);
            text2.setText(""+productServingSize);

            TextView text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calories);
            text3.setText(""+productCalories);

            TextView text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalfat);
            text4.setText(""+productFat);

            TextView text5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saturatedfat);
            text5.setText(""+productSaturatedFat);

            TextView text6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.transfat);
            text6.setText(""+productTransFat);

            TextView text7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cholesterol);
            text7.setText(""+productCholesterol);

            TextView text8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sodium);
            text8.setText(""+productSodium);

            TextView text9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalcarbohydrates);
            text9.setText(""+productCarbs);

            TextView text10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fiber);
            text10.setText(""+productFiber);

            TextView text11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sugar);
            text11.setText(""+productSugar);

            TextView text12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.protein);
            text12.setText(""+productProtein);

            TextView text13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vitamina);
            text13.setText(""+productVitaminA);

            TextView text14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vitaminc);
            text14.setText(""+productVitaminC);

            TextView text15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calcium);
            text15.setText(""+productCalcium);

            TextView text16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iron);
            text16.setText(""+productIron);




        /*
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("name");*/

    }





}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to pass this kind of information between activities in the way you're doing now, you should make your Product class [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and pass the object instead of manually set all the flags the way you're doing it now.

Then once you retrieve the Product in your productdetail activity, you use the getter and setter on the object, and once the user is done, you pass it back to your previous activity.

However the right way of doing what you want to do is to use [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html): intents are not supposed to be used to pass persistent information like products between activities.

Comment: can you provide me with code samples on how to do it. im a noob sorry

Comment: Complete code would be too long, but here are the steps you need to follow:

1. store your products in a content provider: when you're creating the products, you [add](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#modifying) them in the content provider.

2. Now instead of passing the product through the intent, you will pass the product ID instead and in the productdetail activity you will [load](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#querying) data from the provider

3. Once you're finished adding removing, then you save again.

Comment: i just want the boolean to be changed depending on the button

Comment: The problem is that you want to change the boolean in the original product, but because you're not storing them anywhere you will need to pass data back and forth. You need to restructure your code in the way I described in my previous comment (I edited it, since I sent it by mistake before finishing it).

Comment: @user1072908: StackOverflow users are here to answer specific questions, not to do your job for you!